# How it it possible to load Doctrine table definitions from environment variable

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm

I have a project, which uses Doctrine. I would like to run the same code on multiple customer's server. The only probjem is, that some of the table's have a different name. Unfortunately not just the prefix is different. For example the user table is `a_user` in one db, and `user_table` in the other, but the columns I would like to use are the same.

Is it possible to read the Entity table names from an environment variable? I have no idea how to solve this issue, since it has to be defined in the annotation, like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="tablename")
 */
```

If I manually change the table names in the annotation in each customers code, then it works. But I would like to avoid this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `EntityManager` is expected to have a [`getClassMetadata`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.4/class-Doctrine.Common.Persistence.ObjectManager.html#_getClassMetadata) method (since it implements the `ObjectManager` interface). This method will return a [`ClassMetadata`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/class-Doctrine.ORM.Mapping.ClassMetadata.html) instance which allows you to access the configuration of your classes including the underlying table name with `getTableName`:

```
$entityManager->getClassMetadata('App\Models\YourEntity')->getTableName();
```